# The domain of $f(x)=\sqrt{\frac{1-\cos(x)}{1+\cos(x)}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

$$f(x)=\sqrt{\frac{1-\cos(x)}{1+\cos(x)}}$$
It's obvious that this: $$\frac{1-\cos(x)}{1+\cos(x)}\geq0$$
and this $$1+\cos (x)\ne0$$
$$x\ne\pi+2k\pi, k\in Z$$ are the conditions of the function's domain.

If I made a table with cases and changed $\cos (x)=t$, I'd get the result:
$x\in(\pi,2\pi]$
But the solution is $x\in R\setminus(2k+1)\pi, k\in Z$.

I've also come to this:
$$tan^2\frac{x}{2}\geq0$$
from which is obvious that that's any number (but $\pi+2k\pi$), so it's $x\in R$, but is there any way I could solve this without the "universal change" I did in this exercise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is $x\neq \pi + 2k\pi = \pi(2k + 1)$. (I simply factored out $\pi$ from each term in your sum.) So the domain is $ \mathbb R\setminus \pi(2k+1)$, which agrees with the solution you've given.

Note that $-1\leq \cos x \leq 1$. So the numerator in the square root will always be non-negative, and the denominator, aside from the value $\cos x = -1$, is always positive, too. So the function is defined for all $x \neq \pi(2k+1), \;k\in \mathbb Z$, as you found.

Comment: How do I conclude that both num. and denom. are always going to be positive, because maximum values of cosx are -1 and 1, and in the fraction, there is always a "1" next to the cosx, so minimal value is 0, and that's still not negative? Ok.

Comment: Yes, The numerator and denominator will be non-negative at all values, save for where when the function is undefined. So yes, the minimal value of the numerator is zero, and the minimal value of the denominator is zero (where the function is undefined.)

Answer (score 1):

We need a nonnegative radicand, true.  Note, however, that both numerator and denominator are nonnegative for all $x$. That means the only problematic values of $x$ are those where the denominator is $0$. These occur wherever $\cos x = -1$, which is when $x$ is an odd multiple of $\pi$.